# why is the voltage zero across the resistors in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEzpEo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: because V = IR ?

Comment: @Icy How do you know current is zero?

Comment: How much DC current flows thru a capacitor?

Comment: @Andyaka It's supposed to be fully charged

Comment: Assuming V1 is DC with a frequency of 0 hz (no fluctuation), once the capacitor is charged it'll act as an open.

Comment: The clue is in the way the capacitor is drawn, with no connection between the plates.

Comment: Fully charged means the charge is not changing and consider that current is rate of change of charge, how much current is flowing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>The answer is, it is, and it isn't.</strike>

You have missed one critical piece of information in your question, when. At steady-state, or during the transient period when the voltage is first applied.

It seems you added the information in the comments. It is fully charged, i.e. steady-state condition.

---

In the transient the capacitor will charge up through the resistors until it reaches \$1\mathrm{V}\$. Once the capacitor has reached this voltage (i.e. it is fully charged), assuming it is ideal and the voltage source remains constant, then you will have:

$$V_s=V_c$$

Clearly that means all the voltage is dropped across the capacitor, so there cannot be any voltage across the resistors.

---

For completeness, we can look at the steady state condition in another way. The reactance of a capacitor (similar to resistance, but frequency dependent), is given by:

$$X_c = \frac{1}{2\pi fC}$$

Where \$f\$ is the frequency, and \$C\$ is the capacitance. At DC, the frequency is \$0\mathrm{Hz}\$, so the reactance is:

$$X_c = \frac{1}{2\pi C\times 0} = \frac{1}{0} = ∞$$

So what will the current be if the reactance is infinite? \$I=\frac{V}{X_c}=0\$. If there is no current flowing, there can be no voltage across the resistors \$V=IR=0\times R=0\$.

Answer (score 2):

[Falstad's simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/) might be helpful for your understanding. Here's your circuit with the voltage shown on a green/gray scale:

[image: Falstad sim capture]

Notice how the voltage is constant (+V) across the entire top of the circuit. The entire bottom of the circuit is at zero volts. You can't tell from this picture, but the dots representing current are not moving.

What's going on here is that at DC, a capacitor acts like an open circuit. (It's a pair of conductors with a gap between them.) Since the circuit isn't complete, there's no current, and thus no voltage drop across the resistors. That's just Ohm's law.

Physically, all of the charges in the top half of the circuit have the same electric potential energy relative to the bottom half. Since they're not moving, there's no change from one side of the resistor to the other.

Answer (score 1):

> It's supposed to be fully charged

If the capacitor is fully charged it is not taking any more charge i.e. no more charge is being passed through it. Given that Q=CV in a capacitor and also that the rate of change of charge is current, there can be no current flowing through the circuit. With no current flowing through the resistors, there can be no voltage across them (apart from self-generated thermal noise but that's a different story).